# Keras-TF learnable division/arbitrary operation layer

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am searching for a layer that performs an element-wise division of the input but of course the **parameters of this division must be learned**, just as those of a standard conv2D layer.

I found this: 
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Multiply

but i don't think its what i want, because i want the division parameters to be **learned**, not divide 2 layers.

With a dense layer, dot products are computed, which is NOT what I want. I am looking for ELEMENT-WISE multiplication/division.

Comment: This is effectively the same as a Dense layer without biases.

Comment: Indeed. No need to explicitly model a division, since a division is equivalent to a multiplication (x/2 :== x*0.5), which is what happens by default in a neural network layer.

Comment: No, I think you are making a mistake, by default dense nn its the dot product: w^T x = w1x1+w2x2+...+wnxn I dont want to sum! I want ELEMENT-WISE multiplication/division... what do you think?

Comment: if you have an idea, I would be very interested.

Comment: anyone has an idea?

Comment: @Machupicchu, I see that you have asked a question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47289116/element-wise-multiplication-with-broadcasting-in-keras-custom-layer regarding this issue. Is your issue resolved? If so, can you please share the solution so that `community` can benefit from it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample code for a `Custom Layer` that performs an element-wise division of the `input` with the `parameters(Weights)` of this division learned during Training, is shown below:

```
%tensorflow_version 2.x

from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import Input
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Flatten, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model, Sequential
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Layer
import numpy as np

class MyLayer(Layer):

    def __init__(self, output_dims, **kwargs):
        self.output_dims = output_dims

        super(MyLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        # Create a trainable weight variable for this layer.
        self.kernel = self.add_weight(name='kernel',
                                      shape=self.output_dims,
                                      initializer='ones',
                                      trainable=True)


        super(MyLayer, self).build(input_shape)  # Be sure to call this somewhere!

    def call(self, x):
        # Dividing Input with Weights
        return tf.divide(x, self.kernel)

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return (self.output_dims)

mInput = np.array([[1,2,3,4]])
inShape = (4,)
net = Sequential()
outShape = (4,)
l1 = MyLayer(outShape, input_shape= inShape)
net.add(l1)
net.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
p = net.predict(x=mInput, batch_size=1)
print(p)
```

Hope this helps. Happy Learning!